# Нужна запятая перед словом "это"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть два похожих предложения:

(1) *И конечно же, **первое,  что** я сделала – **это** пожадничала.*

(2) ..*.и чуть ли не **единственное,  что** сохранилось наиболее полно от всего ее наследия, – **это** церковь Богородицы.*

Одинаковая или разная грамматика? В первом предложении мне не хочется ставить запятую.

Comment: Одинаковая. Понимаю, почему не хочется, но нужно (по структуре).

Comment: А вы уверены? А мне кажется, что она разная. В первом случае один глагол раскрывает содержание другого. А во втором случае тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (единственное - это церковь). И вообще сейчас запятые не в моде, их по возможности стараются не ставить. Книжки читаете?

Comment: Да, примеры очень разные, но структура совпадает - всё-таки слово "*первое*" главное. Употребление запятой и тире зависит от структуры. Вот другая структура (с вводным словом): *Во-первых, что я сделала - это пожадничала.* Подобное получается, если в вашем примере не поставить запятую. Как-то не сталкивался, что если смысловой перевес идёт к придаточному, то запятую можно не ставить.

Comment: Что я сделала? Пожадничала.  Местоимение ЧТО имеет условное значение, это не дополнение, это обычный вопрос, на который отвечает глагол. Поэтому грамматика разная, в первом случае присоединительная конструкция.

Comment: *Первое - это (я) пожадничала.* Без запятой оно "вводное" (а это неверно) и придаточное исходит не от него. Просто слово "*первое*" очень несамостоятельное. Но главное не придаточное, а то, что это действие первое. Вашу логику я тоже понимаю.